# How can I easily toggle between Dvorak and QWERTY keyboard layouts from a Linux system console?

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, console, dvorak, qwerty

I switch between [Dvorak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_keyboard_layout) and [QWERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY) keyboard layouts and frequently find myself with mismatched layouts on my host operating system and a Linux virtual machine.

How can I easily switch the layout when I have the wrong layout set?

Note that I'm talking about the command-line-only system console here, not a terminal window in a GUI.

Comment: This might also be helpful http://superuser.com/questions/598405/how-do-i-switch-to-dvorak-across-multiple-oss#comment741771_598405

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution to be to create the following aliases in my `.bashrc` file:

```
alias asdf="sudo loadkeys dvorak"
alias aoeu="sudo loadkeys us"
```

Now, when I find myself with the wrong layout, I type the same four keys on the home row to switch layouts.

The only issue I had with this was that it could be difficult to enter a password for the `sudo` command when the wrong layout is enabled. There are two solutions to *this* problem, but they may be a security issue in some environments:

1. Use a strong-ish password comprised only of numbers, symbols, and the letters M and A (they're the same for both Dvorak and Qwerty).
2. Set the `suid` bit on `/usr/bin/loadkeys` so it automatically runs as root (and you don't need to run it with `sudo`). I used the command `sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/loadkeys`. Note: I needed to install the `console-data` package beforehand.

**Edit**: added excellent `suid` suggestion from [ssmy](https://superuser.com/users/64436/ssmy).

Comment: Nice password workaround. Might be a security issue, but maybe loadkeys can be set suid?

Comment: Yeah, my password suggestion would not cut mustard in a production environment. On my personal systems, I always disable SSH password access to force RSA key authentication, and so only type a password either for `sudo` or when on the system console.