# How do I switch to Dvorak across multiple Operating Systems

Tags: linux, windows, mac

**EDIT: I am answering my own question, after not finding a combined guide anywhere. Others, feel free to post an answer.  Additionally there doesn't appear an answer illustrating the pitfalls and techniques of switching in Linux and Windows.**

I work in a mixed environment of Linux, Mac and Windows systems.

I prefer to work in a modified Dvorak. How do I switch to the Dvorak keyboard layout on these various systems?

Comment: My initial reaction was to downvote because the question does not show any research attempts of the OP. But then it turns out that the OP is also the one giving the answer, which is fine by SO standards.

Comment: But confusing. Liam, I suggest you edit the question and include a final remark pointing to your own answer.

Comment: I agree with Jan. I see -2/+1 now, so looks like people missed the fact that you self-answered. Wording it better might help, it certainly looks like a homework question as it stands now.

Comment: I think fattening out the main question would help. It would be an extensive edit, but talking about the scenario "I work in a mixed environment of linux, mac and windows systems, and I prefer to work in dvorak. How do i switch to dvorak on these systems" may work better. Right now it looks kinda bare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Windows

Windows comes preinstalled with the Dvorak keyboard layout by going to  `Control Panel->Regional and Language Options->Languages->Details....`

Windows 8 is the 1st version of Windows to support [switching the keyboard layout for all open](https://superuser.com/questions/13324) Windows.  If you are attempting to switch the layout of all open windows in less then Windows 8 I advise downloading an Autohotkey script.  The scripts don't need Admin rights but needs the [same rights](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1890351) used as the other windows to work properly.  Alternatively [PortableKeyboardLayout](https://superuser.com/questions/242112) I believe can work.

I use [Dvorak](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_keyboard_layout). It is an Autohotkey script that you can that allows yout to enable and disable qwerty and Dvorak between all applications by hitting the CapsLock Key.  The scripts don't require administrative rights.

Alternatively you can use a program like [Keyla](https://code.google.com/p/keyla).  Maybe even [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/)
Portable Keyboard Layout to create custom keyboard layouts in windows.

## OS X

Dvorak is one of the preinstalled input sources that can be selected in System Preferences > Language & Text > Input Sources.

- The default Dvorak keyboard layout can be modified with Ukelele (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/257199/arbitrary-key-remapping-on-a-mac)).
- You can use [changeInput or KeyRemap4MacBook](https://superuser.com/a/588581) to assign shortcuts for switching to specific input sources.
- KeyRemap4MacBook can also be used to [make holding a key change the input source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60053/toggle-the-keyboard-language-by-holding-a-button).

## Linux

In most Unix based OS's there are two ways in which you can temporarily change the keyboard layout.  You can change the keyboard layout in the GUI(x11) interface or in the console interface.

## Online

You can type Dvorak online at [branah.com/dvorak](http://branah.com/dvorak) or [inputking.com](http://inputking.com).

There also have been attempts to [detect the keyboard layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306132/translate-javascript-keycode-into-charcode-for-non-u-s-keyboard-layout-i-e-az) in the browser, so you could potentially switch the keyboard layout through the browser online.

## Physical Switch

Additionally you can get a physical doggle called [QIDO](http://www.keyghost.com/qido/), that switches between Dvorak and QWERTY manually.  There are actually keyboard layouts on Amazon.